# ¿Cuál es el análisis gramatical del verbo "ser" en el sentido "en realidad"?

Tags: gramática, verbos, colombia

Hace poco me topé con la siguiente frase:

> Las muchachas de hoy en día ya no inventan nada **están** **es** pendientes de otras vainas. 
> De aquí para allá, cuando llegábamos a Juan Blanco, una loma altísima antes de llegar a Hato Viejo, **iba** **era** temblando. *Cassiani Ortiz, J. (2018) Un diablo al que le llaman tren. FCE.*

¿Este uso del verbo "ser" tiene alguna explicación gramatical?

Otros ejemplos similares:

> No estamos tristes, **estamos** **es** cansados. 
> No estábamos tristes, **estábamos** **era** cansados.
>
> No está haciendo nada de sol **está** **es** lloviendo muchísimo.
>
> No queremos dormir, **queremos** **es** bailar.
>
> Juan no dijo que quería helado, **dijo** **fue** que quería galletas.
>
> — Finalmente cómo te fuiste a Guatavita?
> — [Pensaba irme en carro pero finalmente] me **fui** **fue** en bus (*ó **viajé** **fue** en bus*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lo que aludes aquí, es lo que se ha venido llamando desde un tiempo a esta parte, (primeros estudios fueron en los años 80' del siglo pasado), construcciones de "**ser focalizador o es enfático**", ejem. "yo vivo es en Bogotá", un tipo de construcciones que se pueden encontrar no solo en Colombia, sino también en Venezuela y otros países del entorno, utilizadas frecuentemente en telenovelas.

Al ser un tema interesante y amplio, te dejo algunas consideraciones generales y otros enlaces sugerentes por si deseas profundizar en esta cuestión, cada día de más actualidad.

---

***Consideraciones teóricas***

El "**ser focalizador**" es, en términos generales, el empleo de dicho verbo en presente, pasado perfecto e imperfecto en una estructura sintáctica del tipo:

**verbo conjugado + una forma de ser + complemento**.

**Por ejemplo**: «*ellos quieren es poder*», «*y no me respetaron fue nada*», «*yo quería era plata*».

> Sin embargo, hay algunas excepciones que también se consideran como
> usos de SF.
>
> En el corpus de esta investigación se encontraron casos en los cuales
> el verbo ser en esta estructura concordaba en número con el verbo que
> lo antecedía («**estaban eran**…») o, también, se reportaron algunos
> ejemplos en los cuales entre el verbo conjugado y el ser se interpone
> un adverbio: «**me gusta muchísimo es por eso**». Y con respecto a los
> complementos hay una gran variedad: con oraciones de relativo, con
> sintagmas adverbiales, con sintagmas adjetivales, sintagmas nominales,
> sintagmas preposicionales, etc.

Diego Arias Cortés

**El ser focalizador en el Español hablado de Ciudad Bolívar**

http://www.scielo.org.co/pdf/linli/n65/n65a02.pdf

---

Otro análisis llamativo de **Elena Diez del Corral Areta**

*https://www.scielo.cl/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S0719-51762016000200003*

> Resumen:
>
> Desde los primeros estudios sobre el ser focalizador aparecidos a
> finales de los ochenta, se han publicado varias investigaciones que
> profundizan en los aspectos formales de estas estructuras. Sin
> embargo, se cuenta todavía con pocos datos y se desconoce su uso en
> diversas zonas del dominio variacional del español. A ello pretende
> contribuir este trabajo, ofreciendo nuevas muestras sobre su vitalidad
> en una zona de Colombia poco estudiada como es Antioquia, en concreto,
> en Medellín. **El análisis subraya, entre otras cosas, la relación**
> **estrecha que existe entre estas estructuras y las seudo-hendidas, su**
> **amplio uso para focalizar sintagmas preposicionales y verbos**
> **auxiliares en perífrasis verbales, y la relación inversamente**
> **proporcional que parece existir entre su empleo y el nivel
> socioeconómico del hablante**.

Comment: Curioso. Lo uso todo el tiempo y nunca lo había notado.